# On sets symbols C \ D, C x D , $P$(E)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

If I have lets say:

C = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9}

D = {2, 5, 7}

E = (4, 9}

---

what does it mean when I want to list the elements of:

C \ D

C x D

$P$(E)   --> for this I thought it would be {4,9} but I got it wrong

Comment: $C\setminus D = \{c\in C: c\in C, c\notin D\}$ (elements in $C$ that are not in $D$). $C\times D=\{(c,d):c\in C,d \in D\}$, all the ordered pairs $(c,d)$. $P(E)=\{F:F\subset E\}$, set of all subsets of $E$.

Comment: c \ d : { 1 , 3,  9}   ---
c x d: {1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9}  ---
p ( e ): {4},{9},{4,9}  ---?
@user160738\

Comment: You got $C\setminus D$ right, for $P(E)$ you missed $\emptyset$, $C\times D$ that's not quite right, what you have there is union of the two set, not set of ordered pairs.